# Node-red view log of last flow run?

Tags: node-red

Is is possible to view somewhere when the last flow ran, and whether it was succesful or not? I have a flow that starts with an inject node, which is set to run every hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really

The best you could do is add a debug node to the end of your flow and set it to output to the console as well as the debug tab. This way you could look at the console to see that the flow ran to the end.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I ended up doing.